# ruby on rails; ERB templates - how to fomat content in file without html tags but instead using something like markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I'm making an erb template for views, what is easiest way to format content within the views?

say i'm putting one sentence like "This is **5x** greater than ..." in the view.

I don't want to put Strong tag to bold it everytime I want to bold something in the template.

Is there something like markdown I can do directly within the view file?

I was using HAML, and there was a way using markdown gem but it seems it doesn't work for erb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAML does offer the shortcut * asterisks * for bolding something, but if you have to use ERB, I think you're stuck with the `<strong>` tags. If you're looking for faster markup, HAML's probably the way to go (if you have control over that decision).

Comment: I used haml but i prefer erb right now as i'm new to rails and i like seeing the some actual html tags to visualize it.

Comment: Fair enough. Keep in mind, HAML allows you to keep all the tags you want and still be valid markup. I pretty much exclusively use haml if I can help it, but find myself writing inline HTML if there's something that's easier to understand in HTML itself than the thing that will compile to HTML later anyway.